# You're speaking plain HTTP to an SSL-enabled server port

Tags: debian, ssl, https

I'm trying to open site using https://mydomain.com, but always I see:
You're speaking plain HTTP to an SSL-enabled server port.
But with http site works...

I'm using Apache 2.2.22, without nginx.
Here's my apache.conf:

```
NameVirtualHost *:80
Listen 80

<IfModule mod_ssl.c>
    # If you add NameVirtualHost *:443 here, you will also have to change
    # the VirtualHost statement in /etc/apache2/sites-available/default-ssl
    # to <VirtualHost *:443>
    # Server Name Indication for SSL named virtual hosts is currently not
    # supported by MSIE on Windows XP.
    NameVirtualHost *:443
    Listen 443
</IfModule>

<IfModule mod_gnutls.c>
#    Listen 443
</IfModule>
```

vhosts:

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
    ServerName mydomain.com:80
    SSLEngine off
    DocumentRoot /var/www/www-root/data/www/mydomain.com
    ServerAdmin admin@mydomain.com
    AddDefaultCharset UTF-8
    AssignUserID www-root www-root
    CustomLog /var/www/httpd-logs/mydomain.com.access.log combined
    ErrorLog /var/www/httpd-logs/mydomain.com.error.log
        <FilesMatch "\.ph(p[3-5]?|tml)$">
        SetHandler application/x-httpd-php
    </FilesMatch>
    ServerName mydomain.com
    ScriptAlias /cgi-bin/ /var/www/www-root/data/www/mydomain.com/cgi-bin/
    ScriptAlias /php-bin/ /var/www/php-bin/www-root/
    ServerAlias www.mydomain.com
    <FilesMatch "\.phps$">
        SetHandler application/x-httpd-php-source
    </FilesMatch>
    <IfModule php5_module>
        php_admin_value sendmail_path "/usr/sbin/sendmail -t -i -f admin@mydomain.com"
        php_admin_value upload_tmp_dir "/var/www/www-root/data/mod-tmp"
        php_admin_value session.save_path "/var/www/www-root/data/mod-tmp"
        php_admin_value open_basedir "none"
    </IfModule>
    <IfModule php7_module>
        php_admin_value sendmail_path "/usr/sbin/sendmail -t -i -f admin@mydomain.com"
        php_admin_value upload_tmp_dir "/var/www/www-root/data/mod-tmp"
        php_admin_value session.save_path "/var/www/www-root/data/mod-tmp"
        php_admin_value open_basedir "none"
    </IfModule>
</VirtualHost>
<Directory /var/www/www-root/data/www/mydomain.com>
    AllowOverride All
    Options +Includes +ExecCGI
    <IfModule php5_module>
        php_admin_flag engine on
    </IfModule>
    <IfModule php7_module>
        php_admin_flag engine on
    </IfModule>
</Directory>
<VirtualHost *:443>
    ServerName mydomain.com:443
    DocumentRoot /var/www/www-root/data/www/mydomain.com
    ServerAdmin admin@mydomain.com
    AddDefaultCharset UTF-8
    SSLEngine on
    SSLCertificateFile "/var/www/httpd-cert/www-root/mydomain.com.crt"
    SSLCertificateKeyFile "/var/www/httpd-cert/www-root/mydomain.com.key"
    SSLCertificateChainFile "/var/www/httpd-cert/www-root/mydomain.com.ca"
    SSLHonorCipherOrder on
    SSLProtocol +TLSv1 +TLSv1.1 +TLSv1.2
    SSLCipherSuite EECDH+AESGCM:EDH+AESGCM:AES256+EECDH:AES256+EDH 
    AssignUserID www-root www-root
    CustomLog /var/www/httpd-logs/mydomain.com443.access.log combined
    ErrorLog /var/www/httpd-logs/mydomain.com443.error.log
    <FilesMatch "\.ph(p[3-5]?|tml)$">
        SetHandler application/x-httpd-php
    </FilesMatch>
    ServerName mydomain.com
    ScriptAlias /cgi-bin/ /var/www/www-root/data/www/mydomain.com/cgi-bin/
    CustomLog /var/www/httpd-logs/mydomain.com.access.log combined
    ErrorLog /var/www/httpd-logs/mydomain.com.error.log
    ScriptAlias /php-bin/ /var/www/php-bin/www-root/
    ServerAlias www.mydomain.com
    <FilesMatch "\.phps$">
        SetHandler application/x-httpd-php-source
    </FilesMatch>
    <IfModule php5_module>
        php_admin_value sendmail_path "/usr/sbin/sendmail -t -i -f admin@mydomain.com"
        php_admin_value upload_tmp_dir "/var/www/www-root/data/mod-tmp"
        php_admin_value session.save_path "/var/www/www-root/data/mod-tmp"
        php_admin_value open_basedir "none"
    </IfModule>
    <IfModule php7_module>
        php_admin_value sendmail_path "/usr/sbin/sendmail -t -i -f admin@mydomain.com"
        php_admin_value upload_tmp_dir "/var/www/www-root/data/mod-tmp"
        php_admin_value session.save_path "/var/www/www-root/data/mod-tmp"
        php_admin_value open_basedir "none"
    </IfModule>
</VirtualHost>
```

Well, I don't know what to do. I bought Aplpha SSL certificate, it works at least with ISPManager, but I can't open the site using https. Please, help!

ssl.conf:

```
<IfModule mod_ssl.c>
#
# Pseudo Random Number Generator (PRNG):
# Configure one or more sources to seed the PRNG of the SSL library.
# The seed data should be of good random quality.
# WARNING! On some platforms /dev/random blocks if not enough entropy
# is available. This means you then cannot use the /dev/random device
# because it would lead to very long connection times (as long as
# it requires to make more entropy available). But usually those
# platforms additionally provide a /dev/urandom device which doesn't
# block. So, if available, use this one instead. Read the mod_ssl User
# Manual for more details.
#
SSLRandomSeed startup builtin
SSLRandomSeed startup file:/dev/urandom 512
SSLRandomSeed connect builtin
SSLRandomSeed connect file:/dev/urandom 512

##
##  SSL Global Context
##
##  All SSL configuration in this context applies both to
##  the main server and all SSL-enabled virtual hosts.
##

#
#   Some MIME-types for downloading Certificates and CRLs
#
AddType application/x-x509-ca-cert .crt
AddType application/x-pkcs7-crl    .crl

#   Pass Phrase Dialog:
#   Configure the pass phrase gathering process.
#   The filtering dialog program (`builtin' is a internal
#   terminal dialog) has to provide the pass phrase on stdout.
SSLPassPhraseDialog  builtin

#   Inter-Process Session Cache:
#   Configure the SSL Session Cache: First the mechanism 
#   to use and second the expiring timeout (in seconds).
#   (The mechanism dbm has known memory leaks and should not be used).
#SSLSessionCache         dbm:${APACHE_RUN_DIR}/ssl_scache
SSLSessionCache        shmcb:${APACHE_RUN_DIR}/ssl_scache(512000)
SSLSessionCacheTimeout  300

#   Semaphore:
#   Configure the path to the mutual exclusion semaphore the
#   SSL engine uses internally for inter-process synchronization. 
SSLMutex  file:${APACHE_RUN_DIR}/ssl_mutex

#   SSL Cipher Suite:
#   List the ciphers that the client is permitted to negotiate. See the
#   ciphers(1) man page from the openssl package for list of all available
#   options.
#   Enable only secure ciphers:
SSLCipherSuite HIGH:MEDIUM:!aNULL:!MD5

#   Speed-optimized SSL Cipher configuration:
#   If speed is your main concern (on busy HTTPS servers e.g.),
#   you might want to force clients to specific, performance
#   optimized ciphers. In this case, prepend those ciphers
#   to the SSLCipherSuite list, and enable SSLHonorCipherOrder.
#   Caveat: by giving precedence to RC4-SHA and AES128-SHA
#   (as in the example below), most connections will no longer
#   have perfect forward secrecy - if the server's key is
#   compromised, captures of past or future traffic must be
#   considered compromised, too.
#SSLCipherSuite RC4-SHA:AES128-SHA:HIGH:MEDIUM:!aNULL:!MD5
#SSLHonorCipherOrder on

# enable only secure protocols: SSLv3 and TLSv1, but not SSLv2
SSLProtocol all -SSLv2

# Allow insecure renegotiation with clients which do not yet support the
# secure renegotiation protocol. Default: Off
SSLInsecureRenegotiation off

# Whether to forbid non-SNI clients to access name based virtual hosts.
# Default: Off
SSLStrictSNIVHostCheck off

</IfModule>
```

Comment: What are you using to open the site? A browser (which one?) or the command line - what command?

Comment: Safari Mobile, Chrome Windows, Mozilla Windows.

Comment: SSL Mod enabled, + Mod Rewrite, Mod Headers.

Comment: Have you restarted the server with the current configs?

Comment: Yes, many times.

Answer (score 1):

Converting existing websites/applications from http to https has numerous "gotcha's" to look out for -- after the server change is made.  By no means complete, but following are some of the things which I've had to deal with.  Just a Jumping Off Point -- for items to check in order to minimize WTF moments.

Allowing ssl connections in whatever (web)application framework you had previously installed is of course one. (wordpress, drupal, joomla, ...)

Making appropriate changes in any .htaccess files (should not change all https to http).

If you have any domain redirects to your domain, they may need to be tweaked.

Also, to make sure that end users are not getting warning messages/icons showing up when viewing your website via an https:
Suggest that you thoroughly examine references to external resources(javascript, css, pictures) loaded into your page to make sure that they are not using `http://` rather than `https://`.

Suggest to not just check webpages, but also error pages.

And of course, if you have any "plug-ins" or using third-party add-on apps, need to scrutinize anyplace they are used.

All of the above items have been thing which I've had to fix when moving websites to a server which has "Let's Encrypt" for my SSL certificates.  I kept the "original websites" available on the old server, and in a couple of instances pointed websites back to that server while I sorted out everything that needed fixing.

Answer (score -3):

Problem solved.
It's all because of my framework. I needed to allow ssl connections.
Thanks everyone for help)

Comment: Welcome to Unix & Linux! It's good to hear that you found the cause of your problem.  You could make your answer more helpful for future readers by explaining *how* you diagnosed it, and in particular, which evidence will identify this problem when it's seen elsewhere.